# Android - Two setViewContent in one Activity - one in xml, one in java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I have recently built an application that shows you a camera preview on screen.

```
package com.street.lamp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.io.IOException;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {
private Preview mPreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("hoera");
    // Hide the window title.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    try{
        mPreview = new Preview(this);
        setContentView(mPreview);
        System.out.println("hoera");
        }
    catch(RuntimeException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
SurfaceHolder mHolder;
Camera mCamera;

Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    try {
       mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
        // TODO: add more exception handling logic here
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}

}
```

Above this is my main screen code, and as you can see i have setContentView twice.
now, i know that setting it twice will only show the latest but i haven't found any other solution. this is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="Hello World" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:focusable="true" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.18" android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do i include both contentviews?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setContentView` override the whole content for your current activity. If you want a layout that **includes** some dynamic components (like your preview), then the preview needs to be part of the main layout, and be added at runtime in the specific component you defined.

Something like:

```
....
setContentView(R.layout.main);
....
final ViewGroup locationForMyPreview = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.preview_location);
mPreview = new Preview(this);
locationForMyPreview.addView(mPreview);
....
```

This `R.id.preview_location` `ViewGroup` can be defined as any type of layout in your main layout (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, whatever).

Your `main.xml` becomes something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="Hello World"     
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:focusable="true"    
        android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.18" android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/preview_location"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```